# how can i compile two or more lex file in my routine

Tags: yacc, lex, redefinition

now i want parse the php file, asp file or jsp file,
lex_php.l yacc_php.y is used to parse php file,
lex_asp.l yacc_asp.y is used to parse asp file,

then i have main, main will call different parse by input type

but when a compile and link them, output redefine error, how can i do?
Makefile like this

```
LEX=flex
YACC=bison
CC=g++
OBJECT=main         #the execute target

$(OBJECT): main.o lex_php.o  yacc_php.o lex_asp.o  yacc_asp.o
    $(CC) yacc_php.o yacc_asp.o -o $(OBJECT)

main.o: main.c  yacc_php.h  lex_yacc_php.h yacc_asp.h  lex_yacc_asp.h Token.h       WebShellFilter.h
    $(CC) -c main.c

lex_php.o: lex_php.c  yacc_php.h  lex_yacc_php.h
    $(CC) -c lex_php.c

lex_php.c: lex_php.l
$(LEX) -o lex_php.c lex_php.l

yacc_php.o: yacc_php.c  lex_yacc_php.h
$(CC) -c yacc_php.c

yacc_php.c  yacc_php.h: yacc_php.y
$(YACC) -d yacc_php.y -o yacc_php.c

############### ASP
lex_asp.o: lex_asp.c  yacc_asp.h  lex_yacc_asp.h
$(CC) -c lex_asp.c

lex_asp.c: lex_asp.l
$(LEX) -o lex_asp.c lex_asp.l 

yacc_asp.o: yacc_asp.c  lex_yacc_asp.h
$(CC) -c yacc_asp.c

yacc_asp.c  yacc_asp.h: yacc_asp.y
$(YACC) -d yacc_asp.y -o yacc_asp.c

clean:
    @rm -f $(OBJECT)  *.o
```

i think, the yacc_asp.o and yacc_php.o both include yyparse, yytext, and mamy other same functions, so maybe output redefine error.

but how resolve this problem, help me, thanks you so much

Answer (score 2):

You can use the flex option `--prefix=foo` (or `%option prefix="foo"` in the .l file) to change the names on all the symbols (so you get a `foolex` function instead of a `yylex` function).  With bison, you can use the `%name-prefix "foo"` option in the .y file for the same effect.

Just choose one distinct prefix for each parser/lexer pair.

Comment: thank you very much, adding the prefix can resolve the redefinition problem, :-)